# Error creating WPF projects

Tags: visual-studio

I am having a problem with WPF projects. Whenever I try to create a WPF project I am getting the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction, Version=4.3.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try repairing your Visual Studio installation. You should also mention which version of Visual Studio you're using.

Comment: It worked. Thanks....